# Anyone recognize this bike frame?

Tags: identify-this-bike

My brother recently passed away, and I'm trying to figure out how much his carbon-fiber 21-speed road bike might be worth.  There's no obvious labeling.  I've searched online... seems like key characteristics are shape/tapering of frame segments, shape of frame segment joints, location/style of ports for internal cabling.  Alas, haven't found any matches :^(.  Photo below, and many more photos at:

https://bicycle.oddotter.org/

My sincere thanks to anyone who can offer any leads/help/advice!

[image]

Comment: Just a guess, but 7sp and carbon suggests Calfee to me. https://calfeedesign.com/calfee-history/

Comment: The other obvious possiblity is getting a generic chinese carbon frame and putting all the components from your old bike on it. FWIW, that really looks like a shade tree bike mechanic upgrade. That frame is way too small for a rider that needs that much seatpost and handlebar height.

Comment: My guess for the frame would be Alibaba special, and the rest is built from random discount bin / leftover parts. Carbon and 7-speed Sora is an odd combination.

Answer (score 1):

Start by exploring some of the identifiable items:

- Campagnolo triple crankset, Campagnolo Athena brakes, and Campagnolo Centaur front derailleur - all from different groupsets.
- Shimano Deore MTB derailleur - from a different manufacturer
- Squishy gel saddle
- The sheer quantity of spacers under the stem.
- Panasonic Panaracer all-round touring/commuter tyres
- Completely unbranded rims and frame, but apparently carbon fibre
- 7 speed block
- Suspension seatpost - not ever found on fast bikes.

I can't see anything on the brifters or the wheel hubs, but based on the pictures that is a **mongrel bike** made of random items.

**Now don't take that badly**, it is not an insult.   It just means there's no big decal on the frame with a brand.   You would be quite justified getting a decal professionally made that says "Drew'sBro" (or his name) and putting that on.

As for worth, well that's outside the scope of this website.  Just list it on craigslist or ebay with "pickup only" and see how the bidding goes.  It is worth what someone's prepared to pay for it.   Your other option is to simply ride it, perhaps in his memory.

Comment: Come to think of it... "mongrel" would be an awesome decal, in fancy-style like Wilier's logo....   https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTM8ys3lbMZVAwMEhOaytFYYuakwiSYlbK3genDlHye94YSl309

Comment: Add to your list the (heavy) suspension seat post usually found on low end comfort hybrids. And the front DR is Centaur, so none of the Campy components are even from the same group. Definitely a parts-bin build. That and the poor fit make me think he got the frame cheap or free from someone and just tried to make it work with what he had.

Comment: Also, the shifters look like Shimano Sora 8s shifters or equivalent. The RD looks like an old Deore, which is an MTB derailleur. I would be surprised if it indexes correctly.

Comment: @WeiwenNg - Road shifters are compatible with MTB rear derailleurs, and Deore was commonly used with drop bars on touring bikes. It's the front DR/levers that aren't compatible between road and MTB. I currently have an 8 spd Sora shifting an STX rear DR, and it indexes perfectly.